# MongoDB .findOne scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with var scope.

```
var max;
    ClassModel.findOne({ class: '1a' }, function (err, class1a) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        max = class1a.members;
        console.log(max);
    });
console.log(max);
```

Why first log logs proper value, but second logs undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second `console.log` shows `undefined` because `findOne` of mongoose is asynchronous. When you show the first `console.log`, the result has been processed, in the second not.

> Mongoose async operations, like .save() and queries, return
>   Promises/A+ conformant promises. This means that you can do things
>   like MyModel.findOne({}).then() and yield MyModel.findOne({}).exec()
>   (if you're using co).

One thing as you can do is to check when it is done, something like..

```
 var max;
 var query = ClassModel.findOne({ class: '1a' }, function (err, class1a) {
     if (err) return handleError(err);
     return class1a.members;
});

query.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // will show class1a.members value
});
```

[Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

Comment: Thanks, it works! What if i wanted to return max and use it in different function instead of console.log?

Comment: I edited again, take a look.